# SoundCloud Javascript API SC.Connect Bug

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

The user is no longer logged in after refreshing the page.

Im guessing this is cookie related.

Thanks, James

Comment: You'll have to describe a _lot_ more about your program if you want help debugging it.

Comment: I was going to check if it was a bug on SoundClouds end before looking into this further, which seems so, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are rewriting the session management in the SC JS SDK at the moment, to make it work across all browsers. we hopefully have it out by the end of next week and should resolve the issues at the moment.